# Permission Error Prevents PostgreSQL Container Initialization in Docker Compose in JMIX

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose

I have configured PostgreSQL to be used as the database for my application, replacing HSQLDB. However, I am encountering a permission issue when trying to initialize the PostgreSQL container within my Docker Compose setup. This issue prevents the proper initialization and functioning of the PostgreSQL container. here is the issue :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fi1Fo.png)

and here is my docker compose file :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bb8vI.png)

I attempted to initialize the PostgreSQL container using my Docker Compose setup, but I expected it to start successfully without encountering the permission issue

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking
a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Are you initializing the PostgreSQL cluster inside Docker? Rerun the `docker compose` command by including the docker file in the command. If you are running a single container inside Docker, you can opt to use `docker run` instead.Check also if the current user has permissions to run the commands.